# Eclipse: Copying over new files while diffing

Tags: eclipse, diff

I'm using Eclipse's graphical diff tool to merge two different branches of a Subversion-hosted project into the workspace.

Line-level differences are simple; I can just click the "Copy Current Change" or "Copy All Non-Conflicting Changes" buttons.

But how do I use the diff tool to copy over file-level differences, i.e. files that exist in a branch repository but not in the workspace?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if eclipse does provide that *exact* feature, but if it does not, you could use an external diff tool (not for diffing files, but to quickly list new files from one directory tree to be copied to another)

Example of [such a tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625/best-diff-tool):

[WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) (See its documentation: [4.1 Copying files](http://winmerge.org/docs/manual/CompareDirs.html#d0e2654))

[image]